# Can I buy a suitcase at LAX airport (Los Angeles)?

Tags: luggage, shopping, lax

I'm visiting LA from London (so don't know the city particularly well), and am flying out of LAX airport later this evening. My suitcase is broken, and I don't have time to shop in the city for a new one because I'm in meetings all day. The LAX website isn't particularly helpful. I'm assuming that there will be some sort of luggage shop, but can't find anything that says there definitely is.

Can I buy one luggage at the airport?

Comment: LAX is a huge airport, so what terminal you are flying out of may be relevant. Depending on how you are getting to the airport, you might pay a visit to the [Westfield Culver City](http://www.westfield.com/culvercity/) (aka Fox Hills) shopping center, which is not far from the airport.

Comment: Right, you should give your terminal/etc to get local info!

Answer (score 7):

Here's a list of stores at LAX:

[Los Angeles World Airpors](http://www.lawa.org/tenantLAXResult.aspx?airport=4&category=38&sindicator=qs)

Based on the name, "Luggage Store - Before TSA" (Ticketing Level) can probably help you out. Depending on your budget there's also a Coach store in the Great Hall as well. I'm sure there are other stores that sell luggage as well but I can't tell from the names alone.

Comment: "Tumi" in the Great Hall is an upscale luggage brand.